# Confirm success of a dataflow job in Cloud functions

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-functions

Is there a way for cloud functions to confirm whether a dataflow job has succeeded or not??

Cloud function that I tried:

```
const google = require('googleapis');

exports.statusJob = function(event, callback) {
 const file = event.data;
 if (file.resourceState === 'exists' && file.name) {
     console.log(file.name);
   console.log(event.data);
   google.auth.getApplicationDefault(function (err, authClient, projectId) {
     if (err) {
       throw err;
     }

     if (authClient.createScopedRequired && authClient.createScopedRequired()) {
       authClient = authClient.createScoped([
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
       ]);
     }

     const dataflow = google.dataflow({ version: 'v1b3', auth: authClient });

     dataflow.projects.jobs.get({
       projectId: 'my-project-id',
       resource: {
         jobId: 'some_number'
       }
     }, function(err, response) {
       if (err) {
         console.error("problem running dataflow template, error was: ", err);
       }
       console.log("Dataflow template response: ", response);
       callback();
     });

   });
 }
};
```

Package JSON:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "googleapis": "^18.0.0"
  }
}
```

The above thing worked for me perfectly **ONCE**.
The response that I got was:

```
Dataflow template response: { id: 'some_number', projectId: 'my-project-id', name: 'cloud-fn', type: 'JOB_TYPE_BATCH', environment: { userAgent: { name: 'Google Cloud Dataflow SDK for Java', support: [Object], 'build.date': '2017-05-23 19:46', version: '2.0.0' }, version: { major: '6', job_type: 'JAVA_BATCH_AUTOSCALING' } }, currentState: 'JOB_STATE_DONE',........
```

Then it gave an error each time after that saying:

```
problem running dataflow template, error was: Error: Missing required parameters: jobId at createAPIRequest (/user_code/node_modules/googleapis/lib/apirequest.js:110:14) at Object.get (/user_code/node_modules/googleapis/apis/dataflow/v1b3.js:670:16) at /user_code/index.js:22:29 at callback (/user_code/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/google-auth-library/lib/auth/googleauth.js:42:14) at /user_code/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/google-auth-library/lib/auth/googleauth.js:289:13 at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7) at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

Does anyone know anything about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Dataflow CLI to determine if a job failed or succeeded. It lets you list jobs and also check their failed/success/running/cancelled status.

Specifically, to check the state of a single job, you may run:

```
gcloud beta dataflow jobs describe <JOB_ID>
```

For more info check the docs:

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/dataflow-command-line-intf

Comment: Note: A successful job will show "Done" and a failing job will show "Failed" for the state field in the output.

Comment: Okay...and what if I wanted to confirm the same through Cloud Functions code in JavaScript?

Suppose I call a dataflow job thorugh Cloud Functions and after its completion I wanna know if it succeeded or not...

Comment: I assume you're launching dataflow jobs by calling a cloud function, by following the guide here?

https://shinesolutions.com/2017/03/23/triggering-dataflow-pipelines-with-cloud-functions/

In this example they access the Javascript googleApis.
You could write another cloud function which calls the google API's and call dataflow.projects.templates.get. Unfortunately, I can't find documentation/code samples for the JS API. But I think you can call it with the projectId and a jobId parameter.

Comment: Hi @AlexAmato do we have a code sample for this available now? That will really help!!

Comment: Hi @AlexAmato I've updated the post with my latest findings.

Answer (score 0):

The payload is wrong. It should be like below.

```
 dataflow.projects.jobs.get({
   projectId: 'my-project-id',
   jobId: 'some_number'
 }, function(err, response) {
   if (err) {
     console.error("problem running dataflow template, error was: ", err);
   }
   console.log("Dataflow template response: ", response);
   callback();
 });
```

The above code is fetching the job details successfully with Node.js 8 (beta).

Comment: Hi, do you have any idea on how to do this in Java?

Linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53677439/waiting-for-a-job-to-be-executed-in-java-dataflow-api-client-library